# What other options are there besides "click"and " hover" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, hover, checked, toggleclass

In the below example I'm using jQuery's toggleclass to make a box look different when the #button is clicked.

```
$("#button").click(function () {
  $(".box").toggleClass("box-toggle");
});
```

I know that I can use "hover" instead of "click", but I'd like to know the full list of what I can say there aside from hover and click.

Is there a full list of these actions states in jQuery/Javascript somewhere?
Is there a "checked" for radio/checkboxes?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly, but I didn't know to search for "Event Types" initially. Google results for "jQuery click hover" didn't easily lead me to the jQuery event types page. I'm not sure one would easily find that page without knowing what category they were in. I was thinking action states initially. Makes plenty of sense now though.

Comment: Also, I didn't know if these were simply Javascript action types, or if they were specific to jQuery.

Comment: Cancelled out one of the downvotes - it's very hard to search for something when you don't know what it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Category: Events**
These methods are used to register behaviors to take effect when the user interacts with the browser, and to further manipulate those registered behaviors.

[EVENTS LIST](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Also there is checked method to check if radio button is checked or not

```
$('#element').click(function() {
   if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the checked method.

Comment: Your's was the most thorough answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQuery's event selectors:

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 1):

Event selectors:
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

As for the checked you can do:

$('#radioID').is(':checked') and it will return true/false

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this :
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

The page contains a bit more info than you want but you will easily find what you need!!

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) will help you with these.

For example for button events, see [this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/). It is the full list of possible mouse events.

For radio- and checkboxes, you can see the checekd selector also linked from the same page - i can't post a link, as I need more reputation to most more than two links.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if some of those events are unique to JQuery? Or are they all common to Javascript perhaps?

Comment: They are all common to javascript. The jQuery method just binds the events to the selector - they enable you to use this $() selector instead of getElementById etc.